# Props no cambian en ventana modal

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Quiero hacer un tipo de calendario con ventanas modales, pero no se reutilizan correctamente los props en la ventana modal.

El calendario como tal funciona, el problema es que aunque seleccione otro botón en todos me sale la misma información de los primeros props que definí en *App.js*

Este es *fechas.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'
    import '../css/fechas.css'
    
    function Fechas(props) {
        return (
            <div className="general">
                <input type="checkbox" id='btn-modal' />
                <label for="btn-modal" className={props.status}>
                {props.dia}
                </label>
                <div className='modal'>
                    <div className='contenedor'>
                        <header>
                            {props.tarea}
                        </header>
                        <label for="btn-modal">
                                ✖️
                        </label>
                        <div className="contenido">
                            {props.info}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Fechas
```

Este es *App.js*

```
import './App.css';
import Fechas from './componentes/fechas'
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className='contain-principal'>
          
            <div className='contenedor-fechas'>
              
            
            <Fechas
            info = 'tarea'
            tarea = 'ca'
            status = 'lbl-modal'
            dia = '06'
            />
            
            <Fechas
            info = 'tarea'
            tarea = 'car'
            status = 'lbl-modal'
            dia = '07'
            />
            
            <Fechas 
            info = 'sol'
            tarea = 'cara'
            status = 'lbl-modal'
            dia = '08'
            />
    
            <Fechas
            info = 'tarea'
            tarea = 'cara'
            status = 'lbl-modal'
            dia = '09'
            />
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo solucionar el problema.

[image: ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estas enviando un valor "quemado" en a tu componente fecha, lo que significa que su valor toda la vida será lo que ahi envías. Para hacerlo dinámico, dependiendo del enfoque de react que estés utilizando, por ejemplo hooks, necesitas crear una variable utilizando el hook useState, y de ahi asignar los valores utilizando la función que tenga la lógica para modificar esa variable y luego pasar ese valor a tu componente mediante props. Te sugiero hacer el tutorial de react: https://es.reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html es muy simple y te ayudará a entender bien como funciona esto que te expliqué anteriormente.

Saludos.